# BIRT report / combine field from two datasets into one dynamic text box

Tags: eclipse, birt

In eclipse Birt report tool, I have two datasets, each return one row.
Then I have a grid, and inside that, I need to combine one field from each dataset into one, and I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Any ideas?

Should look like that:
DS1.Field / DS2.Field

ANy help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have access to DS1 inside the grid G.

You can place a dynamic text item T inside one of G's cells and bind this item T to DS2.

In the expression builder for T, notice that the category "available column bindings" now shows sub-categrories T and G and that you can insert fields from DS1 and from DS2 into the expression.

Thus you can write

```
row._outer["Field"] + " / " + row["Field"]
// ^-- = DS1.Field
//                            ^-- = DS2.Field
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, the problem I run into is that I need to combine fields in each row from two different datasets.
Row1: DS1.Field / DS2.Field
Row2: DS3.Field / DS4.Field and so on. That's why I can't bind the grid to just one dataset.

Comment: Reconsider your data model. For example, perform the joins with SQL or use a joint data set.